# iOS: Perform NSURLConnection when iphone is in sleep mode or when i press the home button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, background, nsurlconnection

When the iphone is in sleep mode and my application try to execute an http request the delegate methods are not called.
How can i execute an NSURLConnection when iphone is in sleep mode or when i press the home button?

Answer (score 6):

Wrap your connection code in calls to `-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]` and `-[UIApplication endBackgroundTask:]`. This will give you 10 minutes (subject to change on Apple's discretion in future iOS releases) to complete the task in the background once your app moves to the background.